# how to pass dynamic data from pivot sql server to visual studio using context.ExecuteQuery

Tags: c#

hi guys i have this situation i have a store procedure and it work fine , but the problem is when i execute the sp from visual studio becouse i do not have the number of colums coming from sql server it could be diferent columns depends on parameteres i have been tryed with spandoObject but no results i put my code and i hope some one can help me 
the sql server query it is a pivot query that s becouse do not have de colums number coming i need a dynamic class in vs

```
    public List<Dictionary<string, object>> Neg_conceptos_nomina_pivote(string 
    Vaux_cia, DateTime Vaux_Fecini, DateTime Vaux_fecfin, string VauxCcostos, 
    bool Vaux_abierta_cerrada, bool Vaux_checkDeducciones)
        {
    List<Dictionary<string, object>> resultado = new List<Dictionary<string, 
    object>>();

    using (Dat_GrupoFaroDBDataContext contexto_grupofaro = new 
    Dat_GrupoFaroDBDataContext())
     {     
    var resul = contexto_grupofaro.ExecuteQuery<dynamic>
    ("uspconceptos_nomina_pivote  '" + Vaux_cia + "','" + Vaux_Fecini + "','" + 
    Vaux_fecfin + "','" + Vaux_abierta_cerrada + "' , '" + Vaux_checkDeducciones 
    + "'");

    foreach (var item in resul)
    {
    IDictionary<string, object> resultadoitem = new ExpandoObject();
       foreach (PropertyDescriptor Property in 
        TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(item))

         {                                            
         var obj = Property.GetValue(item);           // it never get in here why
         resultadoitem.Add(Property.Name, obj);
         }
 resultado.Add
(new Dictionary<string, object>(resultadoitem));
         }
        contexto_grupofaro.Dispose();
       return resultado;
```

Comment: If you want C-sharp language, you should tag `C#` not `C` and `Sharp`!

Comment: please some one must know how to , help me